# what is Func<TResult> in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

what is `Func<TResult>` in C#?

I have used `Action<T>` but dont know the usage of `Func<TResult>`?

explaination with good example is appreciated please.

Comment: Have you tried google? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx

Comment: goood, those are very good and understandable examples, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Func<TResult>` represents a method taking 0 arguments and returning an object of `TResult`, whereas `Action<T>` represents a method returning void. You need two different delegates as you can't specify `void` as a type argument.

Answer (score 1):

[`Func<TResult>` Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) (an example can be found on the MSDN page).

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of the type specified by the TResult parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`Func` is like `Action` except it returns an object of the last generic type passed in.  So for instance, `Func<string>` takes no parameters and returns a `string`.  `Func<int, string>`takes an `int` as a parameter and returns a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Action is effectively equal to an encapsulation of:

```
void Foo<T>(T arg)
```

Whereas Function would be equal to the encapsulation of:

```
TResult Foo<TResult>()
```

If you do not understand the T or TResult part, take a look at generics:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx